# Cómo puedo hacer un algortimo para decir si es imposible perder en un juego de cartas?

Tags: python

El problema consiste en que recibes dos parámetros, uno un número que son el número de cartas (3-12 cartas) y otro que es una lista con el número de las cartas (1-12). Si es posible escoger 3 números, de izquierda a derecha todos, que el primero sea el número más bajo, el segundo el más alto y el tercero el intermedio (entre ellos), entonces se podrá perder.

A partir de esa información tienes que decir si es seguro que se gane, o si hay alguna posibilidad de perder.

He visto este ejercicio y no he encontrado ninguna solución que funciones al 100%, únicamente para los casos en los que las cartas estén en orden creciente o decreciente, en los que se ganará siempre.

```py
def the_loser(n_cards, cards):
    decreassive = True
    increassive = True
    aux = 13
    for card in cards:
        if card < aux:
            aux = card
            print(str(card) + "1")
        else:
            decreassive = False
            break
    aux = 0
    for card in cards:
        if card > aux:
            aux = card
            print(str(card) + "2")
        else:
            increassive = False
            break
    if increassive or decreassive:
        return "GANAS SEGURO"
    else:
        return "PUEDES PERDER"
```

No soy muy bueno en la programación y acabo de empezar hace poco (-6 meses), además esto no lo hago más que por curiosidad de cómo es posible resolver esto.

Aquí dejo el problema completo por si quieren leerlo tal y como es:

[image: Problema]

Comment: Buenas turral, te recomiendo mirar [Cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer el [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Entre otras cosas, te falta proporcionar más detalles como cuál es el problema, qué has intentado y reduce el texto bro, menudo tostón. Edita la pregunta antes de que empieces a recibir votos negativos

Comment: Tu descripción del problema: _de izquierda a derecha todos, que el primero sea el número más bajo, el segundo intermedio y el tercero el más alto_ no es exactamente igual a la descripción del enunciado: _La banca gana si las cartas descubiertas cumplen la siguiente condición: la primera es la que tiene el número más bajo de las tres, la segunda el más alto y la tercera un número intermedio._ Por otro lado, en los ejemplos proporcionados, no parece que se correspondan al enunciado anterior. Es probable que existan errores en el enunciado y/o los ejemplos.

Comment: El enunciado es ilegible en el modo oscuro. No cuesta nada ponerlo como texto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo he entendido bien, creo que no el siguiente código bastaría

```
def loser(n_cards: int, cards: list):
    try:
        assert 3<=n_cards<=12
        assert len(cards)==n_cards  # cards tiene que tener la misma longitud que n_cards?
    except AssertionError:
        print('Make sure n_cards is an integer between 3 and 12 and cards\'s lenght is same as n_cards')
        return

    for i in range(len(cards)-2):  # Recorremos cartas hasta antes de las dos últimas --> i
        for j in range(i+1, len(cards)-1):  # Recorremos cartas por delante de i y una antes de la última --> j
            for k in range(j+1, len(cards)): # Recorremos cartas por delante de j --> k
                if not(cards[i]<cards[j]<cards[k]):
                    return "PUEDES PERDER"
    else:
        return "GANAS SEGURO"

N_CARDS=5
cards=[9, 5, 4, 3, 2]

print(loser(N_CARDS, cards))
```

Comment: ¿Leiste sólo la descripción del Autor de la Pregunta sin leer la captura del enunciado? Algo falla en ese enunciado o en la descripción del AP. Hay que leer y analizar bien toda la pregunta antes de responder. No queda clara cuál de las dos especificaciones es la correcta, la que da el AP (números que incrementan de izquierda a derecha) o la del enunciado: _primer número más bajo, segundo más alto y tercero intermedio_. Luego, ¿cuál especificación es correcta? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Hay casos que no funciona, igualmente gracias por la respuesta. Y al comentario de @MauricioContreras , ¿en qué momento dice que los números incrementan de izquierda a derecha? Lo pregunto por si no me fije bien.

Comment: @turral lo dices tú,  en tu pregunta. La última oración del primer párrafo: ___Si es posible escoger 3 números, de izquierda a derecha todos, que el primero sea el número más bajo, el segundo intermedio y el tercero el más alto, entonces se podrá perder.___ Eso se traduce como: *los números crecen de izquierda a derecha*

Comment: @turral he editado el código, tenía puesto que los números escogidos tenían que ser de manera descendente y no ascendente, pruébalo a ver si funciona y si no, dime para que entradas falla e intento arreglarlo. En principio creo que debería de funcionar

Comment: @MauricioContreras la verdad que a mí también me ha costado pillarlo. La cosa está en que dados el número de cartas (que en sí da igual porque se intuye con la longitud de la lista "cards") y las cartas (que no tienen ningún orden ni patrón), se debe predecir si hay alguna posibilidad de escoger 3 cartas de izquierda a derecha, de tal manera que la primera carta sea la más baja, ..., .... De lo contrario no habrá opción de pérdida. Al menos eso es lo que he entendido

Comment: @DanielSánchez el problema es que en la foto del enunciado dice algo diferente: ___La banca gana si las cartas descubiertas cumplen la siguiente condición: la primera es la que tiene el número más bajo de las tres, la segunda el más alto y la tercera un número intermedio.___

Comment: @MauricioContreras, muchas gracias, no me había fijado bien

Comment: @DanielSánchez, muchas gracias, ya edite el código y lo arreglé. Era problema de el enunciado, muchas gracias, al final la solución más díficil a primeras es la más fácil.